what to you use for google pay button in react native?
first i did it manually styled a button followed guidline but still they said it was not according to the guidline. so is there any package that i can use.
i tried https://github.com/baugarten/react-native-gpay-button
but when i did all the steps it said
ld not determine the dependencies of null.

Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find :react-native-gpay-button:.
Required by:
project :


Did you manage to have a look at my answer below?

Please have a look at the following library:
https://github.com/google-pay/react-native-make-payment?tab=readme-ov-file#google-pay-button
Here is an example of adding the Google Pay button:
<GooglePayButton
  style={styles.googlepaybutton}
  onPress={checkCanMakePayment}
  allowedPaymentMethods={googlePayRequest.allowedPaymentMethods}
  theme={GooglePayButtonConstants.Themes.Dark}
  type={GooglePayButtonConstants.Types.Buy}
  radius={4}        
/>


I think what you are looking for is the google pay package itself.
Here is a link to the specific button element for the google pay button:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-pay/button-element
